# How to split all at once

Tags: modeling

I'm just curious about
how to split all meshes at once from where i want to do.

If i have this cube and want to split it along to the plane.
[image]

The result is

[image]

And what i want to do :

[image]

Split this all meshes at once.

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to join all the objects, or give them all the same Boolean modifier

Comment: Thanks a lot. :D I didn't think that way.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Bisect* operator can act on multiple objects, simultaneously in Edit Mode:

[image]

Comment: OMG this is great :D Thanks !!!!